# Migrating AD Lightweight Directory Services (LDS) or ADAM data to Azure Active Directory (WAAD)

Tags: active-directory, azure, ad-lds, adam, entra-id

We currently have an ADAM instance that we authenticate our ASP.NET web users against. We have a requirement to replace this instance with an Azure Active Directory instance instead with a new schema design. If required I am happy to migrate the data from ADAM into a Windows Server 2012 AD LDS instance first.

Is there any way I can either copy or sync the data from the ADAM/LDS instance into Azure Active Directory? I have seen that there are tools like DirSync, Azure AD Sync and Azure AD Connect but all of the documentation I have seen so far just references syncing a full corporate AD over to Azure.

I also realise that even if there is a technical solution for migrating the data we then have to battle with the issue of schema mismatch as well.

So far the only ugly alternative I have thought of, in the absence of a supported solution, is to knock up a Powershell script to use LDAP to read user data from ADAM and then write to Azure using the Graph API. I'm pretty certain though that this will at the very least lose us all passwords.

Help would be much appreciated,

Phil